# Using Flask from CGI, possible?

Tags: python, cgi, flask

Is it in fact possible to use Flask from a CGI?

If so, how?  I am aware of the concise and nice looking documentation for [CGI+Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/cgi/) but it looks to me, like the `request.args.get('varname')` function is not working, when run as CGI. It certainly works for me on the same (Apache, Ubuntu 12.10) server when run as WSGI.

I came to the conclusion (or strong suspicion, rather) that `args.get()` is not working, after I ran the CGI script on the command line. It would just not pick up anything in QUERY_INFO.

Am I missing something vital about CGI in general, is it a bug in Flask, or what is going on here?

***EDIT***

*The documentation for Flask is updated in git, but at the time of this writing not yet on the homepage. Just don't use any `print` in your Flask application and CGI should work fine.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The args thing is a red herring.

The problem was in CGI, *any* `print` can mess up the output, and in this case it messed up the headers. Solution: don't `print` any debug info or anything, when run as a CGI.

Also;

["... Google’s App Engine, where execution happens in a CGI-like environment"](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/cgi/)

Apparently Google App Engine is similar to a CGI environment and the same `print` thing [can be an issue there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5453787/193892).